# How to download a video using python?

Tags: python, parsing

i just want to watch many anime, but im so lazy. Ok, if you can help me. I have got a code:

```
import requests
import re
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

site = "https://jut.su/eighty-six/season-1/episode-1.html"
res = scraper.get(site).text
quality = "480"
pattern = r'<source src="(.*?)" type="video/mp4" lang="ru" label="' + quality

season_start = int(site[site.index("/season-")+8:site.index("/episode-")])
episode_start = int(site[site.index("/episode-")+9:site.index(".html")])

start = res.index('type="video/mp4" lang="ru" label="1080p" res="1080"')
hrefs = res[start-200:start+900]
print(re.search(pattern, hrefs).groups()[0])
video = requests.get(re.search(pattern, hrefs).groups()[0])
print(video.text)
```

and one small problem, the site block my last request and give me this

```
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>.
```

I think the problem in ip, where the request comes from. when site sees new ip he blocked the video download link. How to fix it?

Sorry for my English<3

Comment: Gonna be honest, this isn't the place to ask for this sort of thing. My guess would be that if you're getting a 403, it's because the website is blocking you which isn't a problem with your code. Do you need to be signed in to watch videos on that site? If so, then you'd need to include a token. Doing so, however, would require reverse engineering their API which is kinda beyond the scope of this website.

Comment: Authorization is optional, you can watch and download the video without it. If u have a time u can check it https://jut.su/eighty-six/season-1/episode-1.html

Comment: The page straight up doesn't load for me

Comment: ok, thx for try.

Comment: Ok so it loaded after about 10 minutes, and I think I may have found you a simpler solution: right click and choose Save video.

Comment: yes, but, you know, its so boring when you want to download more than 100 videos)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but if you still need an answer:

```
import requests
import re

headers = {'authority': 'jut.su','accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7','accept-language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,ru-RU;q=0.7','referer': 'https://jut.su/search/?searchid=1893616&text=avatar&web=1','sec-ch-ua': '"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"','sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0','sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"','sec-fetch-dest': 'document','sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate','sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin','sec-fetch-user': '?1','upgrade-insecure-requests': '1','user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
site = "https://jut.su/eighty-six/season-1/episode-1.html"
res = requests.get(site, headers=headers).text
quality = "480"
pattern = r'<source src="(.*?)" type="video/mp4" lang="ru" label="' + quality

season_start = int(site[site.index("/season-")+8:site.index("/episode-")])
episode_start = int(site[site.index("/episode-")+9:site.index(".html")])

start = res.index('type="video/mp4" lang="ru" label="1080p" res="1080"')
hrefs = res[start-200:start+900]
url = re.search(pattern, hrefs).groups()[0]
print(url)
video = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
if video.status_code == 200:
    with open('test.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in video: f.write(chunk)
```

you just need to add headers